# Converting from WebClient to HttpClient, problems with sending authentication

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

This works:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + base64;
client.DownloadStringCompleted += getAccessToken_DownloadStringCompleted;
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(URL));
```

However, i need to move it to HttpClient (because i've started using Portable Class Library), so i got this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64);

string response = await client.GetStringAsync(URL);
```

But here the HttpClient fails in the surrounding try/catch saying

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

I don't really see any diff....? What might be the problem?

Comment: Check with Fiddler if both requests are send with the same Authorization header.

Comment: have you tried using client.Credentials instead of headers

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077237/httpclient-authentication-header-not-getting-sent

Comment: The code you are showing is fine.  What is weird is that HttpClient doesn't throw errors when it receives a 400.  Is there other code you are not showing?

Comment: @Darrel Miller, by fails i mean throws... it throws into the catch with the error i posted :-)

Comment: @Jason94  Yeah, I forgot that the GetXXXAsync helper methods call EnsureSuccessStatusCode internally.  Calling GetAsync or SendAsync do not throw on Bad request.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when using the portable HttpClient in a Xamarin.iOS app. I'm occasionally getting a 400 when requesting a resource that the current requester doesn't have access to (it's a third-party service I don't have control over). But I'm EXPECTING this 400 status code in some cases and want to handle it. However, some logic in the HttpClient isn't throwing an exception as I would expect. It just crashes natively. Weird.