# Basic Authorization in header vs Username and password in body

Tags: c#, curl, jwt

I am facing two different situations. First method I can send username and password in body as model. Second method is to use basic auth in Header. Both methods are working fine.
Both methods are used only for first call just to authenticate, and the API returns a jwt token.

First Method:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7122/api/Authentication/token' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "userName": "test",
  "password": "test"
}'
```

Second Method:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://localhost:7122/api/Authentication/token' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 -H 'Authorization: Basic ZzI0N2NmbnlwYzV3cmszaHAwZnU2cTk3N2YzZzYxY2hnODV1NzJzZmJkb3c3LmFwcHMudml2YXBheW1lbnRzLmNvbTowYk9xOHRkMzhMQVF4b3ptaWVqUDYwUzdzQnJkVkQ=' \
 --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Are they rules for what should I use in jwt token?
What is good practice to use?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to ensure everyone's on the same page let me outline a typical JWT-authentication workflow here:

1. User calls an anonymous POST API (no authorization required), with a username and password. API then returns a JWT. That's your `Login` API at line 3.
2. All other API calls require authorization, and so the client sends that as `Bearer [JWT]`. The server then determines if the token is valid and if not returns 401.

As I understand the question, you're asking whether, for (1), it's better to send the u/p through the authorization header using the Basic Authentication protocol (base64 etc) or to just post it in plaintext in the body of the login request.

There are two drawbacks I can see with using the auth header-

- Sometimes headers are logged along the way while request bodies rarely are. Grant you, I think it would be unusual (if not unforgivable) for a system to be logging auth headers, but it's possible. The base64 encoding of course provides no security.
- I have had difficulty in the past with basic auth headers actually going through. I'll just refer you to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077237/httpclient-authentication-header-not-getting-sent) which explores some of the possible pitfalls.

Other than the possibe logging issue, I can't think of any *inherent* issues with using one vs. other though. FWIW, I see APIs all the time that use the plaintext body approach while I've never seen an API that has you log in using basic auth and then returns a JWT.

Hopefully it goes without saying that you MUST ensure your APIs are only accessible through HTTPS. Otherwise you're hosed no matter where you put the password.

That said, if you're designing this from scratch and have access to both ends of the system and they will always be in sync, I'd consider sending a *hashed* password, regardless whether you use the auth header or POST body. As long as your client and server agree on the hashing method and iteration count, that significantly lowers the impact of that data possibly leaking or being logged somewhere. This would require a little homegrown security work though.

As for your other question,

> Are they rules for what should i use in jwt token? What is good practice to use?

Rules? No. Conventions, definitely. Ultimately it's whatever information the application needs to be able to trust the user and give them access. These will be in the form of "claims". There's lots of literature on this but the definitive authority would be the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).

Comment: In both cases i will return a JWT token. I just need to know which of two methods are best practice for sending username and password in first call.

Comment: Ok sorry I thought from your code you already had a login method that pulled the u/p from the request object and were asking about using it again in other API calls. I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: Thank you peter i will clarify question again

Comment: No worries, I read it a little too fast. There are definitely drawbacks with using the auth header vs the POST body for the initial login which I'll outline.

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer suggests to send and accept hashed passwords. Don't!
Passwords should be hashed in the database, but accepting hashed passwords in you API means that if the DB is leaked all your passwords are leaked, simply because I only need to send the hashes I got from the DB to the API and I will be let in.
If you do not accept hashes in the API, the attacker would have to generate a string that has the same hash as the one he sees in the DB, which is the additional security that the hash adds here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).